# Pagina direcionando para sistema em frame é recomendavel?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um sistema em PHP; para acessá-lo uso o script abaixo redirecionando direto a ele dentro do *frame*, assim o endereço fica estático no navegador.

Existe algum problema ou não recomendação para esse tipo de prática?

```html
<frameset rows="0,*" border="0">
  <frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="main">
    <frame name="main" src="https://meusite.com/meusistema.html">
      <noframes>
        <body>

        </body>
      </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o que diz a [especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) W3C que trata das features obsoletas, veja a secção 11.2 Non-conforming features:

> Either use iframe and CSS instead, or use server-side includes to generate complete pages with the various invariant parts merged in.

Ou seja, utilize `iframe` no lugar de `frame`, uma vez que é considerado obsoleto.

Em relação a sua questão, se a sua intenção é que uma página seja aberta dentro de outra, não há problema em utilizar `iframe`. É muito útil quando é necessário inserir algum conteúdo dentro de uma página que não o comporta, por exemplo, uma página PHP em um servidor que só suporta HTML, desde que a página PHP esteja hospedada em um servidor que interprete PHP.